# Which Realtime Database instance I need for Firebase Delete User Data extension

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-extensions

I'm trying to install the [Firebase Delete User Data extension](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/delete-user-data). I only use Firestore so I don't need Realtime Database but to configure the extension, an instance of the realtime database is required.

[image]

I have the realtime database disabled. In order to finish the installation of the extension I have put the name of my firebase project to test.

Question: What instance do I really have to introduce if I don't use the realtime database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... that looks like something they should change in the extension, so I recommend filing a report on the [Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/extensions.

For the moment, you'll have to create a Realtime Database instance in the console, and then select it here. You can select completely disabled security rules for the database, to ensure nobody can write data to it from the client-side SDKs.

Comment: As an instance I put the name of the project and I don't have any database in Realtime Database and the extension works perfectly for me. I guess you can put anything as an instance as long as you don't use the Realtime Database.

I set the rules to block all access just in case. I will open an issue on the github. Thank you! :)